# Prove that sequentially compact set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

We are asked to prove that every sequentially compact set is bounded, and the instructor gave the following answer (using contrapositive):

> Suppose $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can choose $x_n \in K \backslash [0, n]$. Then $x_n$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence, specifically, $x_n$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence that converges to an element in K. So K is not sequentially compact.

I'm trying to formally show why $x_n$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence. I understand that in this way $x_n$ is unbounded, but unbounded sequences may also have convergent subsequences. I try to start with:

Suppose there exists a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ of $x_n$, then $x_{n_{k}}$ must be bounded by $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

And then I'm stuck. Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: I would have written choose $x_n \in K \setminus [-n,n]$. Then you know $|x_n| > n$ for all $n$. If $x_{n_k} \to x$ then the sequence $x_{n_k}$ is bounded, which contradicts the construction of the $x_n$ (since $n_k \to \infty$).

Comment: As copper.hat points out, there is a slight flaw in the argument because the sequence $\{1,-1,2,-1,3,-1,4,-1...\}$ has a convergent subsequence. But the idea behind the proof is sound. We want to generate a sequence where each element is some minimal distance away from each of the other elements. Since our space is unbounded we are able to do that. Then no subsequence can have elements that bunch together to form a convergent subsequence.